# Access disk io data in linux without tools like iotop/iostat to find processes or files with IO

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, io

We have regularly high load average. With the help of a zabbix agent, I could narrow it down to be mainly because of cpu iowait (and lastly disk io). I am not allowed to install any additional packages on the server but have root rights and want to investigate the issue. By now I know the affected partitions.

There are no tools like iostat, iotop, sar, etc. available. So I was looking around if there is, like so often, a (pseudo-)file that contains the info that is read by those tools. Since we use RAID, I first looked into `/proc/mdstat` which gives the mapping of our devices `/dev/mdX` to the disk partitions. Then I looked into `/proc/diskstat` and with the help of https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/iostats.html I could find the partitions that are affected by the most IO.

How can I nail it down to files or processes from here? Can `lsof` be helpful? This is available.

Comment: Have a look into `/proc/PROCESS_ID/io`. This file contains the number of bytes read and written by the process. I understand that the bytes actually transferred to/from disk is not necessarily accurate, but the numbers should help. See the manual page for *proc*.

Comment: On this system, there is no `/proc/pid/io`, only `/proc/pid/fd`. This doesn't get me much further though.

Comment: Have you considered just building the tools locally instead of installing the package? If the computer has the development tools needed it may be easier to bust build them yourself.

Comment: Thanks @miguelbernadi, I did consider it, but the necessary dev tools are not installed. Currently we reduced the load and the system runs fine which is why I didn't continue this too eagerly.